# Git+разные базы на dev и prod

Tags: php, mysql, git, github

Работали так: был dev и был prod, но с единой базой. Сейчас появилась потребность разделить базы, чтобы все заполнение было на dev, если все норм, то базу вместе с файлами с dev пушить на боевой

PHP+Mysql

Но как правильно пушить базу или изменения из базы, понять не могу.

Кто как делает?

Comment: Немного странный кейс, обычно dev и prod базы разделены всегда. Если данных немного, то наверно можно использовать механизм фикстур и миграций (входят в комплект любого уважающего себя веб-фреймворка), если много, то хз даже

Comment: Для подобных задач принято использовать **миграции**. Для PHP хорошей отправной точкой может быть https://github.com/doctrine/migrations